# Using data export tools vs Export to Excel in CRM Online

Tags: dynamics-crm, data-migration

What's the difference between exporting data to Excel directly from one CRM organization and importing it into another one in comparison to using a tool like Data Export Manager or Scribe or Instance Adapter to migrate the data ? (Knowing that I already have my old organization's customizations imported into the new organization.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference is that when you export the data to Excel you can export only a single entity. So If your entities have several relationships you need to import back in order to avoid missing records.

Tools like Scribe or the Instance Adapter are able to deal better with these situations.